# mysql cant write to text field "Because of its length, this field might not be editable " error

Tags: mysql

i have a "text" type field in mysql.

It seems i cant write over a limit of characters on that field through my application, and in manual editing through phpmyadmin i get a warning "Because of its length,
this field might not be editable" on that field.

What is this about? Does this has something to do with max query size???

Should i change TEXT -> MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT to avoid this error? If i do so, will this have negative impact on the performance of the table?

Thank you!

p.s. Collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you are writing to that field. If TEXT is not enough for the amount of data you are writing, you can change to MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT.

For the query size using phpmyadmin you would get a 2MB limit by default. If you want to change that default value you need to edit your php.ini file and find the **upload_max_filesize** variable. Change it to something bigger that will help your job be done.

Comment: mediumtext was the solution. thanks cyrex. i ll keep in mind the upload_max_filesize also for the future ;)